# Function attribute error in python

Tags: python

Here is the function in question:

```
def single_letter_guess(guess,word):
    global guessed_letters
    global lives_remaining
    if word.find(guess) == -1:
        guessesLeft -= 0
    guessed_letters = guessed_letters + guess.lower()
    if all_letters_guessed(word):
        return True
    return False
```

The error is coming from the fourth line and displays :

```
if word.find(guess) == -1:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'find'
```

I'm still pretty new to python and don't really know how to interpret this error message. It should technically be looking for the guessed letter in the string word. I can provide the full code if needed for more context.

Comment: It appears that `word` is a function. How are you calling this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `word` is a function that is passed in so  `word.find(guess)` is causing your error. `word` should be a string if you want to use `find`

I think you may be missing parens somewhere you have set `word = some_function` so you set word equal to the function and not the return value.:

```
In [10]: def foo():
   ....:         return "foo"
   ....: 

In [11]: word = foo # no parens

In [12]: print(word.find("f"))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-9db996b190ed> in <module>()
----> 1 print(word.find("f"))

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'find'

In [13]: word = foo()

In [14]: print(word.find("f"))
0
```

Comment: That was it. I forgot a paren in an earlier function that defined word. Thank you.